# What causes _reduxForm not found, with this.context undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, upgrade, redux-form, react-router-dom

Bear with me, this will be long.
Even though I am still a beginner to react and redux, I still wanted to upgrade our application to the newest version of react. This are some of the dependencies:

- **react:** from v16.5.0 to v16.13.1
- **redux:** from v3.7.2 to v4.0.5
- **react-redux:** from v5.0.6 to v7.2.0 (I know this is a huge change, especially from v6)
- **react-router:** from v3.0.5 to react-router-dom v5.0.12
- **redux-form:** from v7.0.3 to v8.3.2

This is the init for routes(I reduced it to login, want to test it step by step):

```
<IntlProvider
        locale={config.locale}
        defaultLocale={config.defaultLocale}
        messages={config.messages}
      >
        <Provider store={store}>
          <NotifyProvider>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
              <FetchProgress />
              <SplashScreen />
              <HashRouter>
                <div>
                  <Route path="/login" component={() => compose(injectIntl, injectNotify)(LoginContainer)} />
                  <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/login" />} />
                </div>
              </HashRouter>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
          </NotifyProvider>
        </Provider>
      </IntlProvider>
```

When I start the application I get this error:

**Invalid prop "_reduxForm" supplied to LocalizedField, should be a Object.
Detected errors (1): 1. Invalid value undefined supplied to Object**

So this is not found in the context. My context is undefined. This error comes from this:

```
export default function ...(Component) {
  class LocalizedField extends React.Component {
    
    ...

    static contextTypes = propTypes({
      _reduxForm: t.Object,
    });

    render() {
      const {
        _reduxForm: { intl, intlPrefix },
      } = this.context;
```

And my Component is:

```
export function TextField({
  label,
  input,
  meta: { touched, invalid, error, warning },
  defaultValue,
  helperText,
  ...custom
}) {
  return (
    <_TextField
      label={label}
      placeholder={label}
      error={touched && invalid}
      helperText={(touched && (error || warning)) || helperText}
      {...input}
      {...custom}
    />
  );
}
```

I read about the context and I thought I understood it but I guess I didn't. How can I see what exactly is in the context? And how can I get this information here without having to pass it as props. This changes in the code regarding _reduxForm are from 2016, what changed?

And... I tried everything I could find on the Internet. So I googled a lot before. But I don't even understand where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

it needs to use the PropTypes.. something like below:

```js
static contextTypes = propTypes({
      _reduxForm: PropTypes.object,
    });
```

Comment: For checking of propTypes I'm using tcomb instead of prop-types. Why should that be a problem?